# Customized permission for IIS6 websites

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6

Is it possible to allow a user (or group of users) permission to view and edit websites settings using the IIS Manager snap-in without giving them administrative privileges on the Windows 2003 server?  Ideally it would be nice to give that user/group permission to only selected websites and/or application pools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature doesn't exist in Windows 2003/IIS6. There is an option that is not supported by Microsoft though:
http://www.winserverkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/iis-security/2147/HowTo-manage-IIS-via-MMC-SnapIn-without-admin-rights

http://msmvps.com/blogs/bernard/archive/2005/05/08/46074.aspx

Windows 2008/IIS7 supports admin delegation out of the box.